# Google Glass and Web RTC - approaches

Tags: android, google-chrome, webrtc, google-glass

I'm trying to set up a local Web RTC call between a PC and Google Glass in a private Wireless LAN network.

I was able to build a quick hello world app on Glass. I changed this app that way, that this app connects to my localhost (which is 192.168.42.1. in my case) to the specific Web RTC Page running on a local Webserver.

Here's the buildView method:

```
private View buildView() {
String url = "http://192.168.42.1/mobilertc";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
return null;
}
```

This WebRTC enabled html page works if a tablet connects to it.
However, the build in Browser of the Glass does not support the GetUserMediaAPI of WebRTC (that's what the error message says).

My question is now, if somebody knows a working approach to establish a WebRTC connection to a PC. Is "pure browser based Web RTC" generally possible on Google Glass?

Ideas that come to my mind are
1) Using Chrome browser on Glass that supports Web RTC -> is a Chrome installation on Glass possible?
2) Using a App for WebRTC like Bistri (but that is not a pure browser based solution)

Some comments / working approaches / ideas / alternative approaches from you would be highly appreciated.

Thank you 
Tom

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to use Chrome/WebRTC on Glass. The only way is to use a native application that embed aWebRTC SDK like Bistri.